# Can I initialize a value to a pointer?

Tags: c++

```
int *p;
*p=100;
cout<<*p;
```

Is this correct or it should give some error?

Comment: set the value to a variable then set the pointer to that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically looks ok, but of course you can find out what happens by simply running it.

However, consider that you are storing a value in a location that is unknown (we don't know where `p` is pointing) hence the resulting behavior is unknown (ie ***undefined behavior***) too.

Comment: don't u think by writing the statement int *x; we are allocating space in the memory and storing 100 in that space.

Comment: @som You are creating a pointer, which really doesn't point to any allocated space. Then you are storing a value in that pointer. Then you try to access that location - that's trouble.

Comment: if it is not pointing to any allocated space then by default what value a pointer variable have? If we assign zero to the pointer variable then would it be correct? And please tell me what happens in the memory when I simply declare a variable pointing to int?

Comment: @som the problem is that the behavior of an uninitialized pointer is undefined. For more information, see the other answers and find a good book on C/C++ and read up on dynamic memory allocation. It's too much to explain via comments :)  re " what value a pointer variable have" in C/C++ variable don't have default values, unintialized variables may have "junk" in them, ie random values present in memory.

Comment: @som you are welcome, this can be a bit tricky since C/C++ put the responsibility on the programmer to manage memory unlike other languages. This can be a rich source of "challenges" .. :)

Answer (score 7):

This will invoke **undefined behaviour**; you are dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.  However, your code may "work", as that's one possible outcome of undefined behaviour.

Comment: why undefined behaviour ? pointer will point to instruction code. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @gcc: The pointer is uninitialised; it doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 6):

Neither.

It is not correct, but the C (or C++) standard places no requirement on the implementation that it should give any error.

Certain things in C (or C++) are "undefined behavior", meaning that the standard doesn't care what happens. This is one of them. The implementation might make some effort to tell you that something is wrong, but it is not required to. It is your responsibility (as the programmer) to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate some space for the interger.

i.e

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 100;
cout << *p;
delete p;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong.

The primary value which a pointer holds is the address of the memory location that it is pointing to.

The statement int *p, defines p as the pointer.

It has to be initialized by pointing to a variable, lets say x.

After initialization, printing p will give you the memory address of x and printing *p will give you the value that x is holding.

It may perform some function, but definitely wont serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This writes to whatever location the uninitialized variable `p` points to, so it may or may not work (if it does don't think it's ok - it's not!) due to undefined behaviour. Most likely it will crash your program.

A good compiler with the proper options (e.g. gcc's `-Wall`) will show a warning:

> warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function